# Determine the distribution of $Y_i$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, covariance

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $$P(X_i=-1)=P(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}$$
We consider the random variables $Y_i=\max \{X_i,X_{i+1}\}$, $i=1,\ldots , n-1$.

(a) Determine the distribution of $Y_i$, $i=1,\ldots , n-1$.

(b) Calculate the expected value of $Y_i$, $i=1,\ldots , n-1$.

(c) Calculate the covariance of $Y_i$ and $Y_j$, i.e. $\text{Cov}(Y_i, Y_j)=E(Y_iY_j)-E(Y_i)E(Y_j)$, $i,j=1,\ldots , n-1$.

$$$$

For question (a) the r.v. $Y_i$ has the same distribution as the r.v.s $X_i$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question (a) the distribution of $Y_i$ is not the same as the distribution of $X_i$ because we have four possible outcomes for $(X_i, X_{i+1})$ which all have the probability $\frac{1}{4}$:
$$(-1,-1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1)$$
Taking the max of both values we get 1 in three of four cases and -1 in only one case. Therefore
$$P(Y_i = 1) = \frac{3}{4}, \ P(Y_i=-1) = \frac{1}{4}$$

Calculating the expected value with this should be no problem.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: "Determine the distribution of $Y_i$ " means that we give the probability of each value of $Y_i$, right?

Comment: That is correct. For continuous distributions you have to be careful if it is the density function or the (cumulative) distribution function that is searched for. But in this case giving the probabilities of the possible values should be what is searched for.

Comment: Ah ok! As for the expected value, dowe have the following? \begin{equation*}E(Y_i)=1\cdot P(Y_i = 1)+(-1)\cdot P(Y_i=-1)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Great!! As for teh covariance : $$\text{Cov}(Y_i, Y_j)=E(Y_iY_j)-E(Y_i)E(Y_j)=E(Y_iY_j)-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=E(Y_iY_j)-\frac{1}{4}$$ How do we calculate $E(Y_iY_j)$ ?

Comment: For that you have to consider two different cases. Namely the case $j= i+1$ and the case $j>i+1$. For the first case we get that $Y_i$ and $Y_{i+1}$ are not independent and the covariance will be $\neq 0$. For $j>i+1$ we have that $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independet and the covariance will be zero. You can determine the values for $E(Y_iY_{i+1})$ by writing down all eight combinations of $X_i, X_{i+1}, X_{i+2}$ which all have the same probability and work out the values and probabilities for $Y_iY_{i+1}$.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)